# Change the color of tabbar and navigation bar programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The default color of the `UITabBarController` is black while the default color of the `UINavigationController` is blue. I need to change this color to some other color. How can I do this programmatically?

I think I found how to change the color of navigation bar but I don't understand the code
`[navBorder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:200.0f/255.f alpha:0.8f]];`

I don't understand what `colorWithWhite` does?

Anyway how do I add color to the `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the color in iOS 5, set the `tintColor` of the UITabBarController's `tabBar`. Here is an example of me doing it:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/ch19p533tabBarController/p464p475tabBarController/AppDelegate.m

(You can download that project and try it out for yourself.)

The `colorWithWhite:alpha:` is a shortcut for setting a grey, possibly with transparency.

Comment: Yeah, @MichaelDautermann, watch for some really garish and weird interfaces coming up in iOS 5. You can color *everything*!

Answer (score 3):

To change the color of `UITabBar` programatically you can use `tintcolor` property the following line of code will help you out

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor redColor];
```

change the tabbar color

```
tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an Appearance Proxy in iOS 5

```
UIAppearance.h class

@Protocol UIAppearance <NSObject>
+(id) appearance ;
+(id) appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class <UIAppearanceContainer> containerClass,..)
...

@end

#define UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR
```

This will help you to change the appearance of the controls whichever you want...
You can also watch the WWDC 2011 Session Video's "Customizing the appearance of UIKit Controls" for more.

example:-

```
[[UINavigationBar appeareance] setBackGroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It changes the navigation bar image to be navBackground image in the application resouce folder and set the navigation bar metrics to be default.

```
[[UIButton ButtonWhenContainedIn:[CustomViewController Class],[UINavigationController Class],nil] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It will set button's title color red when contained in this hierarchy.